# Volume method not working in Angular new Audio()

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my code

```
        this.sound.src = 'http://*********mp3';
        this.sound.load();
        this.sound.play();
```

I am getting error as "this.sound.volume is not a function" when I use

```
this.sound.volume(0.5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`volume` is not a function. It's property. Try this way.

```
this.sound.volume=0.5;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume

Comment: use this.sound.currentTime = 0;this.sound.pause();

Comment: Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume you get know all properties and functions of volume.